# Why does Automator show 1 result on "Set Value Of Variable" but 2 results in "Get Value Of Variable"?

Tags: variables, automator

See screenshot. Why is this happening? I want 1 result, not 2.

[image: screenshot from Automator]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already have the value of the variable at the end of "Set Value of Variable". Why are you trying to get it again?

Try putting a "View Results" item in place of the "Get Value of Variable". I think you'll find that you already have what you need.

Comment: Whenever I use "Get Value of Variable", my 1 result magically turns into 2, which breaks my workflow. The example I posted demonstrates the problem (it wasn't meant to be practical). Here's a better example, using "View Results": [Click here for new screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/27VYN7Y.png)

Comment: The arrows between the automator workflow actions indicate that the output of the previous action will be passed to the input of the next action. In the case of "Set Value of Variable", it sets the value and passes it on to the next action. In the case of "Get Value of Variable", it accepts the value from the previous action and appends the value of the variable you're looking up. Try putting a "Activate Fonts" action in between the "Set" and "Get". Since "Activate Fonts" disrupts the chain of passing values along, the "Get" method only returns the singular variable.